# Oracle Query Date Range

Tags: sql, oracle

This query takes 16 minutes. Is there a faster way?

```
select INIT.MPI_MEMHEAD.MEMIDNUM 
from INIT.MPI_MEMHEAD 
inner join INIT.MPI_AUDHEAD 
on INIT.MPI_AUDHEAD.audrecno = INIT.MPI_MEMHEAD.CAUDRECNO 
where(INIT.MPI_AUDHEAD.audctime+0)  >= to_date('01-JAN-14') AND (INIT.MPI_AUDHEAD.audctime+0) <=  to_date('01-APR-14')
```

Comment: What is the query plan?  How big are the tables?  How selective are the conditions?  What indexes are available?  Why are you, apparently, explicitly adding 0 to `audctime` in order to, presumably, prevent an index on that column from being used?  Are your statistics up to date?

Comment: There is not enough information about your data, your statistics, no explain plan. Nothing to go on. However, if `INIT.MPI_AUDHEAD.audctime` has an index on that column, by adding a 0 to the column value you are purposely telling the optimizer to **not** use that index.

Comment: Here is the explain plan: [http://i.imgur.com/uWOAwoX.png](http://i.imgur.com/uWOAwoX.png) Also, the tables are quite large. Millions of records.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can revise "where(INIT.MPI_AUDHEAD.audctime+0)  >= to_date('01-JAN-14') AND (INIT.MPI_AUDHEAD.audctime+0) <=  to_date('01-APR-14')" to "`where INIT.MPI_AUDHEAD.audctime between date '01-JAN-14' and date '01-APR-14'`".

Second, if you are always to select this table in one quarter by INIT.MPI_AUDHEAD.audctime, you can alter this table to a partition table by audctime. As below:

```
CREATE TABLE MPI_AUDHEAD(
      audctime DATE
) PARTITION BY RANGE(audctime)
(
PARTITION part01 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2014-01-01 00:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')) TABLESPACE tbs01,
PARTITION part02 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2014-04-01 00:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')) TABLESPACE tbs02,
);
```

)

Third, add an index on audctime.

For your reference.

Comment: For one more question: Is that OLAP or OLTP?

Comment: Love the partitioning advice, but the first paragraph prevents a +1 because it contains syntax errors

Comment: Thanks for the post, I will look into this. I have never worked with partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Your query formatted so it is a bit more understandable:

```
select mh.MEMIDNUM 
from INIT.MPI_MEMHEAD mh inner join
     INIT.MPI_AUDHEAD ah
     on ah.audrecno = mh.CAUDRECNO 
where (au.audctime+0)  >= to_date('01-JAN-14') AND (au.audctime+0) <=  to_date('01-APR-14')
```

I don't fully understand the `where` clause.  The `+ 0` isn't doing anything.  So, you should convert it to:

```
where au.audctime >= to_date('01-JAN-14') AND au.audctime <= to_date('01-APR-14')
```

Assuming that `audctime` is in a date/time format, then the query engine can take advantage of an index.  My recommendation would be to add the following two indexes:

```
INIT.MPI_AUDHEAD(audctime, audrecno)
INIT.MPI_MEMHEAD(CAUDRECNO, MEMIDNUM)
```

These are *covering* indexes, so all columns mentioned in the query are in the indexes.  In addition, they should speed up the `where` clause and the `join`.

Comment: I added the +0 when I was googling different ways to run the query. If it helps, my old query took exactly the same time. (Without the 0"

Comment: @You . . . Seems strange.  It will often prevent the use of an index.

Comment: I am still new to querying databases. It is just inconvenient to search this much data and have it take this long.

Comment: How large are the tables?  And do `audrecno` and `caudrecno` have exactly the same type?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following modified query:

```
SELECT mm.MEMIDNUM 
FROM INIT.MPI_MEMHEAD mm
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT ma.audrecno as audrecno
     FROM INIT.MPI_AUDHEAD ma
    WHERE ma.audctime >= to_date('01-JAN-14', 'DD-MON-YY') AND ma.audctime <=  to_date('01-APR-14', 'DD-MON-YY')
    ) filtered_ma
ON filtered_ma.audrecno = mm.CAUDRECNO;
```

The objective of re-writing the query this way is to join with a smaller subset of the `INIT.MPI_AUDHEAD` table data.

As others have recommended, it would useful to create indexes on the columns that are used for the join and the filter conditions.

Comment: Getting the error: From keyword not found where expected. line 5 column 8.

Comment: @You I have added the missing FROM in the inline view. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: I have ran your query and it now takes 7.5 minutes (thank you). I am wondering if indexing will speed it up even more but I do not know how to index a column nor what repercussions it will have. I don't want to screw anything up in the database.

Comment: @You I think it is very prudent on your part to weigh the effects of creating indexes. Indexes can speed up your SELECT query, but they might also slow down your DML (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) operations.

Comment: Here's an SO question about the creation of indexes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212264/how-to-choose-and-optimize-oracle-indexes I would point out "Do not index columns that are modified frequently." and "Do not index keys that appear only in WHERE clauses with functions or operators."